# Future List of Daylight Savings changeover date-times (UK)

Tags: dataset, utc, timezone-offset

I am looking to write a program that needs to convert from local (clockface) UK time to UTC. As the system I get the data from can't provide the offset, I have to guess it.

I am aware of the potential flaws with this technique; and am not asking for guidance on how to do this. What I am asking for is, does anyone have a list of the British Summer Time change dates for the next (say) 50 years?

I know it's not strictly a programming question; so if anyone can suggest a better StackExchagne site to ask on I'll move the question there.

Alternatively, can anyone recommend an api (java or .net, ideally) that could be utilised to generate such a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is pretty easy to generate in Excel.

The changeover is the last Sunday in March and October, so have the following columns:

- A: Last day of month (31)
- B: Month (3, 10, 3, 10, ...)
- C: Year
- D: Date for last day in each changeover month(`=DATE(C3,B3,A3)`)
- E: The weekday for that last day (`=WEEKDAY(D3)`)
- F: the day of the last sunday (`=D3-E3+1`)
- G: The hour of the changeover (1,2,1,2,...)
- H: The formatted datetime of the changeover (e.g. `=UPPER(TEXT(F3,"dd-MMM-yyyy"))&" 0" &G3 & ":00:00"`)

Obviously this could be simplified to use less columns; but doing it this way allows the columns to be expanded easily as far as you want into the future